# Does renaming Windows domain impact SharePoint?

Tags: 2010, domain

**My setup is following:** I have SharePoint 2010 running on Windows 2008R2 and another server running SQL Server 2008. AD DS/Domain controller is on same server as the SharePoint.

My SharePoint isn't using the AD for authentication or profiles, it is configured to sync with LDAP server from totally elsewhere.

My question is if renaming the Windows domain name will have any impact on SharePoint, and if there will be any need to reconfigure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will break SharePoint.  You'll have to re-install it (and preferably not on a DC).